# Github actions - cancel/manually trigger workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a public repo, is it possible to enable canceling/manually triggering workflow for people who are not the repo owners?

I have added the below part to manually trigger the workflow.

```
on: workflow_dispatch
```

I am able to do the above operations, but people who are raising a PR or something to my repo cannot cancel or manually trigger it.

Is there any kind of permissions that need to be given to that person to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They need [Collaborator access for a repository owned by a user account](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-user-account-settings/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository#collaborator-access-for-a-repository-owned-by-a-user-account). For an organization repository, they need at least the [Write role](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-access-to-your-organizations-repositories/repository-roles-for-an-organization#repository-roles-for-organizations).

> **Manually running a workflow**
> Write access to the repository is required to perform these steps.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow

> **Canceling a workflow**
> Write access to the repository is required to perform these steps.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/canceling-a-workflow